# Static Table View with Cell that fill visible screen area

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I want to create a static table with 7 cells that fill the rest of the screen with taking into account the status bar and nav bar. I override the methods bellow but I am not getting the expected result. What I am missing?

```
    override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let tableHeight = (CGFloat(tableView.bounds.height) - CGFloat(64))/7

    return tableHeight }
```

the picture shows that my 7 cells do no occupy all the screen [image: static table view with 7 cells]

Comment: What's your current tableView constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let tableHigh = (CGFloat(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.height) - CGFloat(64))/7

    return tableHigh }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! :-D. What makes the difference?

Comment: because there was no need to remove 64 from table height

Comment: this will work better as your code might not work because of auto layout

Comment: @irkinosor Please approve so that this question can be closed

Comment: Ha I have to wait four minutes to be able to approve :-P . Thanks

Comment: Thanks and any time :)

Answer (score 0):

This is another good solution:

```
override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let tableHeight = (tableView.bounds.height - tableView.contentInset.top - tableView.contentInset.bottom) / 7

    return tableHeight
}
```